# Building Apps for Smart wearables like MOTO 360

Tags: google-apps, motorola, sony-smartwatch

I wish to start building apps for wearable smart tech like Moto 360 but considering my experience in tech. ( next to zero ) I am having difficulties in going about it.
Please consider to answer this question and help.
How should I start going about it ? Are there guides available? What language must be used ?

Comment: Flagged as off topic. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask to learn about what types of questions are off topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: Wow. You don't even want to help.